# Update AccountUser via WSProxy

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

Has anybody been able to update the AccountUser object. For example, disable a user or delete a user. I was not able to find any documentation about it. I almost got my WSProxy code working the only part that I am getting an error on is setting the UserID. I am getting the following error:

User 0 does not have permission to edit ACCOUNTUSERS on account MID.

```
prox.setClientId({"ID": MID, "UserID": 'felipe.diaz'});
var updateObject = {
AccountUserID: 'AccountID',
ActiveFlag: 'true'
};

var options = {SaveOptions: [{'PropertyName': '*', SaveAction: 'UpdateAdd'}]};
var res = prox.updateItem('AccountUser', updateObject, options);
```

Answer (score 4):

I've spent some time trying to workaround this, but get the same error as the one you reported. I've also tried using the SSJS/AMPscript API functions and get the same error.

This is a known issue with the SOAP API (WSProxy is a wrapper for the SOAP API). Refer to [this known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003ffAQAQ).

For now, it appears the only workaround would be to enable 'Enable Username and Password for Web Services' in Setup > Security > Security Settings and then create a user with API User with an Administrator Role. Then, you would be able to make an HTTPPost request to the Marketing Cloud SOAP API with basic authentication. Not ideal, I know.

Comment: When making your HTTPPost SOAP API call, make sure you publish your CloudPage. You can't see the response unless you publish it. Since these pages are public, I would advice you to create a url key parameter and display data when the key is set.

Answer (score 1):

The SOAP API error “User [n] does not have permission to edit ACCOUNTUSERS on account [MID]” has [been fixed](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003ffAQAQ) in the July 2020 release.

Comment: Hey @eliot, I managed to get this working in Postman (July 2021) but encountering the same above error with WSproxy.